# parse a line to get numbers

Tags: matlab, parsing

I have lines that look like this:

```
tmp='bla bio = 773 node = 6 bib=21 data=118 pewp= 120'
```

I need to get the first and last numbers - 773,120
I tried

```
sscanf(tmp,' %*s %*s %*s %f  %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %f')
```

But without any luck..
The numbers  6 21 118 are random the rest are consts

Comment: When using your commands, the interpreter prints 773 and 120. Where is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found an easy way

```
temp=sscanf(tmp,'bla bio = %f node = %f bib=%f data=%f pewp= %f')
tmp(1)=temp(1)
tmp(2)=temp(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following approach might help:

% Remove all '='
`tmp(strfind(tmp,'=')) = [];`

% Set the key & indices
 
`key = 'bio'`;
 `index = strfind(tmp,key);`

%Extract value 

 `value = sscanf(str(index(1)+length(key):end), '%g',1);`

% To get value of pewp, set key = 'pewp' and repeat above steps